# Как перевести "XY Problem"?

Tags: переводы, аббревиатуры

Перевожу с Меты [статью "What is the XY problem?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem):

[Что такое «Ошибка X–Y» или «XY Problem»?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/709/181472)

Суть самой «XY Problem» вкратце такова.

У пользователя есть проблема (X). Например, надо забить гвоздь. Он ошибочно считает, что эту проблему нужно решать при помощи микроскопа. Правда, при этом микроскопы часто ломаются. Пользователь приходит на сайт и задаёт вопрос: «А где мне купить крепкий микроскоп?» (Y) При этом он ни словом не упоминает о том, что он забивает этим микроскопом гвозди.

Таким образом, участникам приходится почувствовать странность вопроса, догадаться, что именно автор делает неправильно, возможно, задать наводящие вопросы, и выяснить истинную проблему (Х).

---

Вопрос: как перевести этот термин?

- Буквально, вроде «Проблема/ошибка XY»

  - Использовать оригинальные «X» и «Y»
  - Заменить на кириллицу
- Объяснить
- Ввести новый термин

#### Аргументы:

С одной стороны, к латинице мы все вполне привыкли на уроках математики. Плюс, опытные пользователи, приходящие с англоязычных сайтов, привыкли к известному названию «XY Problem». С другой стороны, «Проблема XY» для русского глаза выглядит слегка провокационно, да и смесь языков немного неестественная.

Вот вам краткое объяснение в разных вариантах, чтобы вы могли оценить и выбрать. Если есть ещё варианты - пожалуйста, предлагайте. Править пунктуацию в предложенных ответах почти нет смысла, всё равно это черновой текст и он будет выброшен. Да, и по мере работы я понял, что объяснение даже неточное и не совсем правильное, но это здесь не так уж важно.

---

Я задаю этот вопрос не на мете ru.so, а здесь, потому что мне важно мнение именно экспертов в области языка, а не технических специалистов.

---

Все мои ответы сделаны общими, так что никакой накрутки голосов не происходит, когда вы голосуете за один или несколько вариантов. Если вы не согласны с вариантом - просто не голосуйте за него.

---

Comment: А неужели для такой ошибки нету стандартного названия?

Comment: Кстати, может быть, хорошего перевода и правда нету, и можно _предложить_ новый термин? Например, какую-нибудь красивую метафору или аллюзию на аналогичный общеизвестный сюжет в литературе?

Comment: @VladD: принял правку.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Предубеждение молотка

Предлагаю аллюзию на известную поговорку «когда в руках молоток, всё вокруг кажется гвоздями». Это как раз пример XY problem: подход к решению проблемы исходя из наличия инструмента, а не базируясь на анализе самой проблемы.

(Точно так же программисты, выучившие регулярки, пытаются распарсить HTML, просто не зная других инструментов. [Канонический пример.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags))

Comment: И в качестве примера- легендарный вопрос про эти самые регулярки. :)

Comment: @NickVolynkin: сделано!

Comment: я сначала подумал, что перевод сделали )

Comment: Пожалуй, перепишу вопрос с этой формулировкой. Протестируем создание нового термина.

Comment: Звучит очень не по-русски. Как будто у молотка могут быть (пред)убеждения. Может, лучше "предубеждение о молотке" или "предубеждение о молотке и гвоздях"? В прочем, тоже звучит странновато.

Comment: @LogicDaemon: Ну, метонимия же. Более логичное «предубеждение неумелого столяра» звучит ужасно. Если у вас есть идея получше, выкладывайте в ответ.

Answer (score 5):

Я считаю, что нет смысла сохранять буквенные обозначения, поскольку в русское общепринятое понятие это не сложится. Правильный подход к переводу в таких случаях состоит в ясной передаче смысла: переводом будет то, как назвал бы то же самое носитель русского языка. В самом понятии нет ничего неслыханного - из английского толкования следует, что в русском понимании это обычная "**проблема (неверной) постановки задачи**". Человек пытается решить задачу, понимаемую им в узком смысле (сводя её к выбранному им средству и нацеливаясь на частность **X**), в то время как разумное решение лежит в другой плоскости: нужно сформулировать задачу шире, выбрать другое средство и решать гораздо более простую задачу Y. Пример неверной постановки задачи: "как мне отредактировать это видео в программе **X** (она мне удобна, но что ни делаю, получается плохо)?" - вместо этого вопрошающий должен был уяснить, какую операцию **Y** ему нужно получше выполнить, и спросить о подходящем для этого средстве.

Если же попытаться сохранить буквы, то как минимум заголовок останется непонятым, а содержание перевода самой статьи с упоминанием такого выражения, каким бы способом вы его ни раскрыли, будет критиковать половина технических специалистов.

Comment: Нашел еще формулировку "ошибка неверной рабочей гипотезы" http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/250659/296059

Comment: Ваши рассуждения о правильном подходе к переводу оказались очень ценными. Спасибо.

Answer (score 4):

Я бы перевел как **ошибка домысливания**. В русском языке проблема - это то, что требует решения, а "ошибка" - результат неправильного решения. Здесь, скорее второе.

Слово "домысливание" полностью характеризует причину ошибки и понятно даже человеку незнакомому с английскими терминами.

Comment: Ошибка - лучше подходит, согласен, использую. Про буквенную часть есть такие соображения: русскоязычные пользователи с англоязычного StackOverflow привыкли к формулировке «XY Problem», и я хотел бы заменить её чем-то аналогичным.

Comment: @NickVolynkin напиши «ошибка домысливания (XY Problem)»

Comment: @LogicDaemon: я не согласен с «домысливанием». Проблема в другом.

Comment: @NickVolynkin и в чём же? Или это секрет? см. [домысливать](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/efremova/159779/%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%8B%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C "2. Додумывать с помощью воображения или творческой фантазии, развивать что-либо известное, данное.")

Comment: @LogicDaemon: там в вопросе появился целый абзац объясняющий проблему.

Comment: @NickVolynkin я несколько раз (с паузами в день) перечитал вопрос, думая, что долблюсь в глаза. Не нашел объяснения, почему не *домысливания*. Нашел вот что: «Он ошибочно считает, что эту проблему нужно решать при помощи микроскопа». Собственно, в этом предложении как раз указана ошибка. Ошибка "считания", т.е . рассуждения, не основанного на достаточном количестве исходных данных, т.е. *домысливания*.

Comment: @LogicDaemon хмм. Надо мне тоже ваш комментарий пару дней почитать. :)

Answer (score 3):

## Переводим как «АБ»

> Проблема «АБ» — это распространенная ошибка тех, кто задает вопросы в сети StackExchange. У человека есть проблема А, он предполагает, что она решается с помощью инструмента Б и уточняет детали решения, задавая вопрос «Как использовать Б»? При этом для эксперта в А очевидно, что Б полностью не подходит и вопрос должен звучать: «Как или каким инструментом решить А?».

Answer (score 2):

Это ошибка — следствие недопонимания мотива вопроса с одной стороны и поспешности с другой. Её называют ещё и логической. Переводить X и Y не следует. Чтобы форма «Проблемы XY» для русского глаза не выглядела провокационной, надо, думаю, растащить X и Y: **Проблема X—Y** (или **X—Y Проблема**).

Comment: Отличный вариант. Между буквами — именно тире с пробелами? А вариант с дефисом без пробелов возможен?

Comment: Без пробелов,— так компактней, и именно тире, чтоб не читалось минусом.

Answer (score 2):

#### Проблема истинной причины [ошибки]

На мой взгляд, *"XY Problem"* говорит именно про ошибку последовательности постановки задачи - участник пытается решить проблему Y, которая на самом деле не является "истинной" проблемой.

Спешу предложить несколько измененных вариантов.

1. Проблема понимания истинной причины [ошибки].
2. Проблема причины и следствия [ошибки].

Answer (score 1):

## Оставляем латиницу

> Проблема XY — это распространенная ошибка тех, кто задает вопросы в сети StackExchange. У человека есть проблема X, он предполагает, что она решается с помощью решения Y и уточняет детали решения, задавая вопрос «Как использовать Y»? При этом для эксперта в X очевидно, что Y полностью не подходит и вопрос должен звучать: «Как или каким инструментом решить X?».

Answer (score 0):

## Аббревиатуры

> Проблема «ПР» — это распространенная ошибка тех, кто задает вопросы в сети StackExchange. У человека есть проблема П, он предполагает, что она решается с помощью решения Р и уточняет детали решения, задавая вопрос «Как использовать Р»? При этом для эксперта в П очевидно, что Р полностью не подходит и вопрос должен звучать: «Как или каким инструментом решить П?».

Comment: А почему инструмент назван Р?

Comment: Я голосую за вариант с английской аббревиатурой. Она более информативна, чем русская.

Comment: @PavelMayorov: Р - решение. Изменил текст в итоговой версии, а тут осталась первая версия. http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/709/181472